# How to match cmyk colors between matplotlib and LaTeX

Tags: color, python, matplotlib

I'm plotting something using `matplotlib` and I'm using the `matplotlib.cm.rainbow` colormap. I need to match the same colors in my LaTeX document, but I'm having a difficult time making the colors match between what I get on my plot and what appears in my LaTeX document.

**What do I have to do to get matplotlib and LaTeX to use the same colors?** Even coming close would be a benefit.

The code I'm using to plot in `matplotlib` is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

Fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
indices = range(8)

length = len(indices)
print("\ncolors: ")
for i in range(length-1):
    left = indices[i]
    right = indices[i+1]

    c = pyplot.cm.rainbow(i/length)
    print("i={}, color={}".format(i,c))
    ax.fill_between((left,right), 0,1,
                    facecolor=c, edgecolor=c, alpha=0.25)

# Do the last one
i +=1
left = indices[i]
right = 8
c = pyplot.cm.rainbow(1.0)
print("i={}, color={}".format(i,c))
ax.fill_between((left,right), 0,1,
                facecolor=c, edgecolor=c, alpha=0.25)
```

The output from this is:

```
colors: 
i=0, color=(0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
i=1, color=(0.24901960784313726, 0.38410574917192586, 0.98063477046897773, 1.0)
i=2, color=(0.0019607843137254832, 0.70928130760585339, 0.92328910610548931, 1.0)
i=3, color=(0.25294117647058822, 0.92563765978155632, 0.83018403081555059, 1.0)
i=4, color=(0.50392156862745097, 0.99998102734872685, 0.70492554690614728, 1.0)
i=5, color=(0.75490196078431371, 0.92090551794495368, 0.55236497296050591, 1.0)
i=6, color=(1.0, 0.70054303759329106, 0.37841105004231035, 1.0)
i=7, color=(1.0, 1.2246467991473532e-16, 6.123233995736766e-17, 1.0)
```

[image: matplotlib plot output]

I use the output to define colors in LaTeX using:

```
\definecolor{colorA}{cmyk}{0.5    , 0.0    , 1.0     , 0.0}
\definecolor{colorB}{cmyk}{0.2490 , 0.3841 , 0.9806  , 0.0}
\definecolor{colorC}{cmyk}{0.0019 , 0.7092 , 0.9232  , 0.0}
\definecolor{colorD}{cmyk}{0.2529 , 0.9256 , 0.8301  , 0.0}
\definecolor{colorE}{cmyk}{0.5039 , 0.9999 , 0.7049  , 0.0}
\definecolor{colorF}{cmyk}{0.7549 , 0.9209 , 0.5523  , 0.0}
\definecolor{colorG}{cmyk}{1.0    , 0.7005 , 0.37841 , 0.0}
\definecolor{colorH}{cmyk}{1.0    , 1.2246 , 6.12323 , 0.0}
```

Finally I use the colors in a table (with the `colortbl` package) using the command

```
\rowcolor{colorA!25} 1 & ...
```

However, the colors in the figure don't match the colors in the table and it is aggravating me why it doesn't work. Instead of the `purple, blue, aqua, ...` (I know these are not technical color names) that is seen in the figure, the colors I'm getting are `green, orange, orange red, red, gray red, violet, blue,...` The colors are not even close.

Comment: good luck;)  I think this is a LaTeX issue, I had great trouble matching colors to pdf/eps files.  You might have luck on latex stack exchange as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is simply that `pyplot.cm.rainbow` does not return CMYK values, but RGB + alpha. An excerpt from the docstring:

> ### Returns
>
> Tuple of RGBA values if X is scalar, othewise an array of
>   RGBA values with a shape of `X.shape + (4, )`.

Hence, by using

```
\definecolor{colorname}{rgb}{a,b,c}
```

where `a,b,c` are the first three values from `rainbow`, the colours match. (For `colorH` note that the `g` and `b` values are (very close to) 0, not 1.22 and 6.12, but that was perhaps just a copy-paste error.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{colorA}{rgb}{0.5    , 0.0    , 1.0     }
\definecolor{colorB}{rgb}{0.2490 , 0.3841 , 0.9806  }
\definecolor{colorC}{rgb}{0.0019 , 0.7092 , 0.9232  }
\definecolor{colorD}{rgb}{0.2529 , 0.9256 , 0.8301  }
\definecolor{colorE}{rgb}{0.5039 , 0.9999 , 0.7049  }
\definecolor{colorF}{rgb}{0.7549 , 0.9209 , 0.5523  }
\definecolor{colorG}{rgb}{1.0    , 0.7005 , 0.37841 }
\definecolor{colorH}{rgb}{1.0    , 0.0    , 0.0     }
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{colors}

\begin{tabular}{*{8}{c}}
\cellcolor{colorA!25}\phantom{\rule{1cm}{4cm}} &
\cellcolor{colorB!25}\phantom{\rule{1cm}{4cm}} &
\cellcolor{colorC!25}\phantom{\rule{1cm}{4cm}} &
\cellcolor{colorD!25}\phantom{\rule{1cm}{4cm}} &
\cellcolor{colorE!25}\phantom{\rule{1cm}{4cm}} &
\cellcolor{colorF!25}\phantom{\rule{1cm}{4cm}} &
\cellcolor{colorG!25}\phantom{\rule{1cm}{4cm}} &
\cellcolor{colorH!25}\phantom{\rule{1cm}{4cm}} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the kind of answer making this forum so valuable: down to the very detail of the technic.